# Cost of HTTP Call for Angular 2 + PHP app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I'm implementing server side session in PHP + Angular 2 Application and this is my plan:

1. Creating a table session_info in MySQL and it returns unique session id.
2. To make sure session is valid every time state changes i.e new route is picked

I am making an HTTP call to check session is valid or not in ngInit for each component but I'm concerned about the cost of making an HTTP call on every ngInit. Is this right way of doing this ?

Comment: Http calls are among the most expensive thing you can do in your app. I don't see any benefit of checking the session id in every component. If it is valid for one component, why would it be invalid for the next? Why not just share the id status using a service. What is this session id for anyway?

Comment: Once the user provides valid credentials I am providing a unique Id - session Id to differentiate between users.
Idea is to maintain a session for the user - if there is no session ID I will log the user out.
Do I do these using cookies , will that be a better approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Use JWT web tokens on the server. The server needs to ensure that the calls come from a user that is authenticated.

Provide an API on the server that allows you to fetch the status whether he is properly authenticated.

Use a globally shared service in your Angular application where the current logged-in status is maintained. This way you only need to ask the server once. You can refresh using an interval (from minutes to hours) if you think this is necessary.

Every component or service that wants or needs to know the logged-in status injects this service and can get the up-to-date information from there.

For communication between components see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

See also

- https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage
- https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/
  (didn't check these articles, just searched and they came up on top).

Comment: Got me understand the problem = now have another issue how to decode and use JWT token generated in PHP application.<br>Saw package angular2-jwt but difficult to comprehend as I am newb to angular world.. can u suggest any tutorial or hints

Comment: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt  I haven't used it myself though.